# Pandas to_sql index starting at 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following to dump a dataframe into SQL:

```
summary_df.to_sql('table', con=self.avails_conn, if_exists='replace', index_label='id')
```

However, the `id` field is autoincrementing and needs to start at `1` (not `0`). Is there a way to do this in the `to_sql` method? Or do I need to update the index before dumping it? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: `summary_df.index = summary_df.index  + 1` ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to change the dataframe before you call `to_sql`, and `summary_df['id']+=1` should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, by setting the index of your dataframe prior to exporting to SQL your table will have an index incrementing from one.

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
                   'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
                   'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})

df.index += 1  # <- increment default index by 1
df.to_sql("second_table", conn)
c = conn.cursor()
for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM second_table"):
    print(row)

conn.close()

#  (1, 1, 2012, 55)
#  (2, 4, 2014, 40)
#  (3, 7, 2013, 84)
#  (4, 10, 2014, 31)
```

If you have a different index you can create a numeric one using `df = df.set_index(list(range(1, len(df)+1)))`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've ended up using `df.index += 1`.